# How to add hyperlink to each part of high-chart's stacked bar chart in php

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I have used high-chart's stacked bar chart code in my webpage. I am trying to add a hyperlink to each part of stacked bar. I have back end data for some accounts which are in state of "completed" or in "query" or "pending". I have prepared the code to display the graph for status of accounts of 5 days. Now i want that when i click on "completed" part of stacked bar for any day, it should open the page containing the list of accounts completed on that day. I have attached the screenshot and code for reference. Thanks.

[click here to see image of the graph for 5 days of week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpljr.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Stacked column chart with data from MySQL using   Highcharts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Account Status',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'No of Accounts'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
             plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },

            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0     auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event to your bars, to do that add this to your plotOptions :

```
series: [],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    document.location.href = 'page.php?cat=' + this.category;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: when i add this code to my script, the graph disappears from the page. Please help me out. I am not getting help from internet. Thanks.

Comment: i am trying but unable to do. as i have used jason, can u please have a look at my above code and give me the code to add for events.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I just tested it, it works for me. Add the code just after `series: [],`